# How can I convert into WSDL this SOAP code?

Tags: soap, xsd, wsdl

I have this snippet of SOAP invocation and I wish to learn how to write the correspective WSDL (1.1 or 2.0, it's the same for me now). With standard data types that's an easy job, but I don't know how to translate into XML schema the attribute type="SOMETHING".

```
<getStuff>
<StuffCode type="ANTANI"> 31337 </StuffCode>
</getStuff>
```

Is perhaps in wsdl i have something like this

```
<xsd:element name="StuffCode" type="xsd:stuffcodetype">
```

and in the XSD I have this:

```
<xs:element name="StuffCode">
 <xs:element name="name" type="xs:int"/>
 <xs:attribute name="type" type="xs:string" use="required"/> 
</xs:element>
```

Comment: What technology stack are you using?

Comment: I'm using just pen and paper, before starting using any technology i wish to understand this properly.

Comment: I can recommend an article about contract-first service design using the MS stack - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee335699.aspx. The explaination of wsdl is very helpful.